# XMLHttpRequest memory leak on server side (php, apache, javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest

Is it even possible that ajax/javascript/xmlhttprequest could cause apache to start eating up memory (other than bomb the host with a ton of requests all in a row)?

I am retrieving data using javascript -- XMLHttpRequest and PHP -- very simply. The data I am retrieving contains a standard pager (Prev, 1, 2, 3, etc., Next) that also contains a lot of onClick events. I know there is concern with creating new events without destroying the old and memory leaks (especially with older IE), but that is all client side, anyways, right?

I'm having an issue running out of memory on the server side and am not sure if I should even look into the javascript or not. I'm 99.99% sure my javascript can't be to blame, because if there was a memory leak, it would be on the client side anyways. But, some XMLHttpRequest techniques are still somewhat new to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't imagine how this would be the client's fault, unless your improperly sending too many requests at one time.

Comment: Memory leaks on the server has NOTHING to do with browsers/JavaScript. Are you opening/closing database connections right?

Comment: @epascarello What about long-polling that isn't configured correctly on the server? That would still be the server's fault, but is caused by a misunderstanding of the client (in a way). That's all I could think of. Or as you're saying, possibly not closing DB connections correctly

Comment: @Ian, An Ajax call is an http request that spools up the server. The client has no affect on the server other than the requests. Memroy leaks comes from something wrong, without seeing php code it is up to the OP to find the lealk[s].

Comment: Thanks. I was more or less trying to rule out the javascript as the culprit, really. Fishing for "How about abc? Have you checked xyz?" scenario's. Long polling doesn't come into consideration with this one. It's really basic, just the first heavy-ish XMLHttpRequest app on the host, so thought maybe I overlooked something.